# Lombok под Eclipse

Tags: java, lombok

Пытаюсь подключить `Lombok` к своему проекту в `Eclipse`, в `pom.xml` прописал зависимости:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.10</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

На класс ставлю аннотацию:

```
@Slf4j
```

Подключается

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
```

но при попытке прописать:

```
log.error("…  exception");
```

Ругается, что нет такой переменной `log`.
Я так понимаю, что плагин ставить для этого не обязательно, он только позволяет увидеть то, что скрывает `Lombok`, или я не прав?
Плагин установить не могу, т.к. на работе политика безопасноcти не дает скачивать `jar`-файлы

Comment: Плагин как раз позволяет IDE понять, что поле `log` будет сгенерировано при компиляции, и не ругаться.

Answer (score 1):

Плагин нужен обязательно.

Он внедряется во встроенный процесс компиляции, который используется не только для компиляции, но в том числе и для проверки синтаксиса.

Без плагина из eclipse можно собирать и запускать только через maven/gradle (т.е. в обход компилятора eclipse), так как и maven и gradle, по сути, запускаются как внешние утилиты. Отладчик, скорее всего тоже не удасться запустить, хотя можно попробовать через remote java application (при этом ругаться на синтаксические ошибки будет все равно). Тесты JUnit встроенными средствами тоже нельзя будет запустить.

Вам не нужно иметь доступ на скачивание jar файлов, чтобы запустить инсталяцию плагина. Если у вас локально сборка мавеном проходит, то значит права yа скачивание maven пакетов есть. И значит, что lombok.jar уже скачан во время сборки мавеном и его можно запустить из локального репозитория maven.

У меня на macos он находится по пути `~/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.12/lombok-1.18.12.jar`. Запустить инсталяцию можно прямо оттуда:

```
java -jar ~/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.12/lombok-1.18.12.jar
```